# Tex Live 2016 bug: "! LaTeX Error: No counter 'd' defined."

Tags: hyperref, texlive, counters, cleveref

I have a file which compiles fine with TeX Live 2015, but which bugs on TeX Live 2016. When compiling with TeX Live 2016, (after I clean up all the non-source files) I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: No counter 'd' defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.27 \begin{defn}

?
```

Please have a look at the following minimal working example, in which I encounter this bug.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{aliascnt}

\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=darkgreen,linkcolor=darkgreen,unicode]{hyperref}

\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\def\defthm#1#2#3{%
  %% Ensure all theorem types are numbered with the same counter
  \newaliascnt{#1}{thm}
  \newtheorem{#1}[#1]{#2}
  \aliascntresetthe{#1}
  %% This command tells cleveref's \cref what to call things
  \crefname{#1}{#2}{#3}}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\defthm{defn}{Definition}{Definitions}

\begin{document}

\begin{defn}
This definition causes trouble in TeX Live 2016, but not in TeX Live 2015.
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've marked it as a duplicate, but actually the title here is more informative, I may change the title of the other one.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: When you do, also remove the [tag:sharelatex] tag.

Comment: I cannot yet confirm that the solution in the other question indeed solves the problem. It solves it for the MWE, but not for the file I'm actually interested in, although I cannot really pin down the problem yet.

Comment: Actually it works.

Comment: @Egbert I'll try to sort out a real fix in hyperref, but probably be the weekend now

Comment: Thanks David! It would be greatly appreciated. We encountered the problem in an open source math book.

Comment: @Egbert can you drop me an email (google my name should show my gmail) I have a version you could test.